# How can I explode a string by an array instead of a string?

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace, explode

I have a string like `012A345B67Z89` that I need to explode by any letter (A-Z).

The result I'm looking for is something like this:

```
$str = '012A345B67Z89';
$result = explode(range('A','Z'),$str);
print_r($result);
```

and get:

```
array(
    [0] = 012
    [1] = 345
    [2] = 67
    [3] = 89
)
```

Ideally in php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try preg_split:

```
$str = '012A345B67Z89';
$result = preg_split("/[a-z]/i",$str);
print_r($result);
```

That should give you the exact output you want (sans the commas):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 012
    [1] => 345
    [2] => 67
    [3] => 89
)
```